# Android test if front camera supports flash

Tags: android, android-camera

I know is possible to detect if camera has flash integrated, using a method like this:

```
 /** 
 * @return true if a flash is available, false if not
 */
public static boolean isFlashAvailable(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
}
```

but if the device has 2 cameras how can I test for each of them if has flash available?

For example on a Samsung S2 device, on native camera application when using the front camera the flash button is disabled, meaning is not available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Paul's answer didn't work for me.

The front camera on a Galaxy Nexus has a valid flash-mode of `FLASH_MODE_OFF`, but it is the only supported option. This method will work in all situations:

```java
    private boolean hasFlash(){
        Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<String> flashModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if(flashModes == null) {
            return false;
        }

        for(String flashMode : flashModes) {
            if(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON.equals(flashMode)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

If your app supports more than just `FLASH_MODE_OFF` and `FLASH_MODE_ON`, you'll need to tweak the if-check inside the loop.

**-- Update --**

Also you can add `torch` for flash in `if` condition if you really need to use torch.

```java
    if (Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON.equals(flashMode) || Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH.equals(flashMode)) {
```

Comment: This is very interesting. Didn't knew that can have just FLASH_MODE_OFF as options... indeed this solutions seems to be better than the one presented by me. thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine for me. I have added one more if condition for `torch` in for iteration. Hope it works for others too.

Answer (score 9):

I figured this by myself and I post here the solution, which is actually very simple:

```
/**
 * Check if Hardware Device Camera can use Flash
 * @return true if can use flash, false otherwise
 */
public static boolean hasCameraFlash(Camera camera) {
    Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    return p.getFlashMode() == null ? false : true;
}
```

The above method is different by this one:

```
/**
 * Checking availability of flash in device.
 * Obs.: If device has 2 cameras, this method doesn't ensure both cameras can use flash. 
 * @return true if a flash is available in device, false if not
 */
public static boolean isFlashAvailable(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
}
```