# How to detect front camera and flash availabiliy

Tags: android, flash, android-camera, android-package-managers, front-camera

Hi I am developing a custom video app. I am able to get the `currentCameraId`  by

```
currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
```

I have two questions to ask:

1) How to detect android devices with only front camera.

Because on tablets with only front camera like in Micromax tab, the `currentCameraId` is 0.

2)  How to check camera flash availability as the below code is not working on some of the phones

```
flash = this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

Please Help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To Check Flash Light is available or not**

```
boolean hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

**To Check Camera is available or not**

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {

}
```

**If you are using API level 9 (Android 2.3) or above, you can do the following to calculate the index of the (first) front-facing camera:**

```
int getFrontCameraId() {
    CameraInfo ci = new CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
        if (ci.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) return i;
    }
    return -1; // No front-facing camera found
}
```

**you can then use the index for the Camera.open**

**For eg**

```
int index = getFrontCameraId();
if (index == -1) error();
Camera c = Camera.open(index);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. How to check if the flash is supported for front camera?

Comment: Check This May This Help You.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400910/android-test-if-front-camera-supports-flash

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public boolean hasFlash() {
        if (camera == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

        if (parameters.getFlashMode() == null) {
            return false;
        }

        List<String> supportedFlashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (supportedFlashModes == null || supportedFlashModes.isEmpty() || supportedFlashModes.size() == 1 && supportedFlashModes.get(0).equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```