# getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH) returns false

Tags: java, android

**Hi guys!**
I created a flashlight app and I checked if flash exists like this:

```
hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flashlight!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    }
```

The problem is on some old devices which has the flash sensor but this method of checking returns false. (for example when I run it on **Vertis 3510 You** or **Serioux  RM X401** this checking method returns false and when I comment those lines it just works fine).
Is there another way of checking if device supports flash? 
Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400910/android-test-if-front-camera-supports-flash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
public boolean hasFlash() {
        if (camera == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

        if (parameters.getFlashMode() == null) {
            return false;
        }

        List<String> supportedFlashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (supportedFlashModes == null || supportedFlashModes.isEmpty() || supportedFlashModes.size() == 1 && supportedFlashModes.get(0).equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Now that Camera has been deprecated since API 21, how to resolve this problem? :)