# Front Flash light in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an app where I want when a user presses a button front flashlight is on. I know how to open a back camera flash light.
But I don't know how to open the front camera flashlight within the same application. Anyone will guide me how to do this?

Comment: Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400910/android-test-if-front-camera-supports-flash). You can easily get support from other resources. I suggest you make sure your code use Camera API 2.

Comment: the given solution only checked either flash is available in the device. while I want to check the availability of flash in the front camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such thing as "Front Flash Light". The only thing I can think of at this stage is the Notification LED light at the front. Even looking at my Samsung S6 Edge device, I cannot find any front flash light on my camera.

The following code only applies to the rear flash light. 
I believe there are three things you will need to do.

1 - Check to see if there is availability for flash on the device 
2 - Set the corresponding permission in your manifest 
3 - Implement the code to operate the flash functions

This code will return a boolean based on the availability for flash feature

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

Next are your permissions in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

The first permission is for the camera, second permission is for the flashlight where you don't have to activate the camera hardware

And finally, the code to turn on the flash

```
Camera myCamera = Camera.open();     
Parameters myParameters = myCamera .getParameters();
myParameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
myCamera.setParameters(p);
myCamera.startPreview();
```

To turn the service off

```
myCamera.stopPreview();
myCamera.release();
```

Additional function to test

```
  CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

  try {
    String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
    cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
    flashLightStatus = true;
    imageFlashlight.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_switch_on);
  } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
  }
```

This may assist in getting the front camera accessibility from getCameraIdList function. Usually, the front camera is at the first position.

Comment: the given solution worked for the back flashlight. while I want to turn on the front flash light..

Comment: @AsmaAhmad please have another look at the answer as I've added additional function to test

Comment: your additional code also work on the back flashlight

Comment: @AsmaAhmad after doing a lot of research, I came to the conclusion that I don't think there is such thing as "Front Flash Light". The only thing I can think of at this stage is the Notification LED light at the front. Even looking at my Samsung S6 Edge device, I cannot find any front flash light on my camera.

Comment: yes, you are right. After so much searching, I also found the same thing.

Comment: @AsmaAhmad I've changed the answer accordingly. I don't know if it's suitable to mark this as the accepted answer to inform others if they come across your question.