# In Android how to check if device has front flash (Camera2 API)

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2

I have developed app that can toggle rear and front flashes. But if a device hasn't got front flash the app crashes. Can I check device front flash availability? Like if front flash unavailable show toast and disable the button.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android test if front camera supports flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400910/android-test-if-front-camera-supports-flash)

Comment: no, it's in 2013 it doesn't work on new api

Comment: Hi @Diorid - what is the API you are working on?

Comment: Hi I'm working on Camera2Api

Comment: use `getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);`

Comment: No it didn't work. I've tried it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this I guess:

```
boolean flashAvailable = cameraCharacteristics.get(cameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
```

***[public static final Key FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE)***

Will be *false* if no flash is available.

If there is no flash unit, none of the flash controls do anything. This key is available on all devices.